# Auto increment column (DataGridView, Microsoft Access)

Tags: c#, sql, database, winforms, ms-access

I have a table `Employee` with a bunch of columns in an Access database. I have already added a couple of rows manually and my ID column is defined as auto incremented (counter).

I'm trying to add a row to the table using the form with the same fields (textBox) except for the ID column of course. The thing is if I add the row with my form, everything works fine but the ID column. In DataGridView it shows `-1`, in the database it shows proper auto incremented ID.

The question is: how to match those IDs? I hope the explanation is understandable.

Here's the code for my Add to DB button.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Form3 main = this.Owner as Form3;

        if (main != null)
        {
            DataRow nRow = main.bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            
            nRow[1] = full_name.Text;
            nRow[2] = position.Text;
            nRow[3] = age.Text;
            nRow[4] = experience.Text;
            nRow[5] = projects.Text;
            nRow[6] = trainee.Text;
            nRow[7] = hours.Text;
            nRow[8] = late.Text;
            nRow[9] = overall_num.Text;

            main.bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nRow);
            main.employeeTableAdapter.Update(main.bestEmployeeDataSet.Employee);
            main.bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();

            main.dataGridView1.Refresh();

            full_name.Text = "";
            position.Text = "";
            age.Text = "";
            experience.Text = "";
            projects.Text = "";
            trainee.Text = "";
            hours.Text = "";
            late.Text = "";
            overall_num.Text = "";
        }
    }

int rc = main.dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;

nRow[0] = rc;
```

I was trying to do this but it only autoincrements the Id judging by the entries I have in DataGridView (I have 3 entries, so I get ID = 4) when in the database, the next ID should be 14 because I deleted a few entries already by testing my delete button.

Comment: _”…it only autoincrements the Id judging by the entries I have in DataGridView( i have 3 entries, so i get ID = 4) when in DB the next ID should be 14…”_ … it should appear obvious that when the user creates a “new” row in the gird, that you need to get the new ID from the DB, not the grid.

Comment: Your `bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0]` must include the Auto-increment ID field. When you add a new Row *manually*: `bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { null, full_name.Text, position.Text, ... }); `, `null` identifies the ID Column, which is auto-incremented base on the DataTable Schema loaded when you filled the DataTable. Check the ID Column's properties and verify the values of the `AutoIncrement` and `AutoIncrementStep` properties. `AllowDBNull` must be `false`.

Comment: ok no, it doesn't work if add raw manually with  null( i get the same IDs -1, -2, -3 etc.) and I'm pretty sure this is not right:
DataColumn d = new DataColumn("id");
 d.AllowDBNull = false;
Also I don't know how to get the new ID from DB, this is my first time working with db

Comment: You **don't** have to add a new Column and you **don't** have to get the ID from the database later. You have to fill the DataTable with a query that includes the ID field (coming from your DB). When you do, the corresponding Column of your DataTable object will include, in the Table Schema, the auto-incrementing ID Field specifics. This if you actually have defined an auto-incrementing ID Field in your Access database (not just a Field named `ID`). Remember to call `AcceptChanges()` **right after** you have filled the DataTable (no matter what method you use to fill it).

Comment: Note that in the snippet a previously posted, to add a new row: (`bestEmployeeDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new object[] { null, ...)`), the ID Field is meant to be the first Field in the DataTable definition. Also, the data type of all Fields must be respected. E.g., if `position.Text` is meant to set the value of an  `integer` Field, you have to convert the value to `integer`. Or whatever that is.

Comment: Do I have to fill the DataTable with a query that only selects the ID field? And then make it a variable to pass in to Rows.Add as fi? I'm not really following, are there any examples I can look at?

Comment: You have to fill the DataTable with a query that selects all Fields, including the ID Field. IF you want to add a Row manually, use the previous syntax and add the data in the correct order and with the correct DataType.